# inserting average of data into a vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I have the following data in test:

```
2011-01-03      2116    
2011-01-03      2120    
2011-01-04      2116    
2011-01-04      2115
```

and the following code:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> >::iterator tk = test.begin();
std::vector<double>tmp;

std::copy(tk->second.begin(), tk->second.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp));
```

with the above code `tmp` contains:

```
2116
2120
2116
2115
```

However, I want to insert the average of `tk->second` for each date into `tmp`. Do I have to write my back_inserter into a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); it++)
{
  double sum = 0.0;
  int count = 0;
  for(auto it2 = it->second.begin(); it2 != it->second.end(); it2++, count++)
  { 
    sum += *it2;
  }
  tmp.push_back(sum / count);
}
```